# Variable number of loops in function (python)

Tags: python, function, loops, nested, python-decorators

here is an exemple of what I would like to do:

```
d1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
d2 = {'aa':11,'bb':22,'cc':33}
d3 = {'aaa':111,'bbb':222,'ccc':333}

def nLoop(*args):

    n = len(args)

    if n == 1:
        for k0,v0 in args[0].iteritems():
            print k0, v0

    if n == 2:
        for k0,v0 in args[0].iteritems():
            for k1,v1 in args[1].iteritems():
                print k0, v0, k1, v1

    if n == 3:
        for k0,v0 in args[0].iteritems():
            for k1,v1 in args[1].iteritems():
                for k2,v2 in args[2].iteritems():
                    print k0, v0, k1, v1, k2, v2

nLoop(d1,d2,d3)
```

My question is: are there some ways to do it without the if conditions? Maybe with the use of decorators?

Comment: Here is not about the number of arguments passed to the function but about the way to add nested loops

Comment: You could look at the module `itertools`. You should also be able to write a function returning a generator, obtain a list of such generators and traverse them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can pass your variable argument list to `itertools.product` (with a generator comprenehsion to convert the dicts to their items), then print the flattened results (since `product` returns tuples of tuples):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools

d1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
d2 = {'aa':11,'bb':22,'cc':33}
d3 = {'aaa':111,'bbb':222,'ccc':333}


def nLoop(*args):
    for t in itertools.product(*(a.items() for a in args)):
        print(*(x for a in t for x in a))

nLoop(d1,d2,d3)
```

The output of this new `nLoop` function is identical to yours (if order isn't considered, since dictionary order may change between runs)

Note that this is a Python 3 compliant solution, but also works with Python 2.

Comment: can you help .my code is little different than that

Comment: If my code isn't helping, maybe you can ask a question refering to this question, and explaining what doesn't work for you ?

Comment: i have reached question limit